# Is there Java Gimp API for manipulating images

Tags: java, api

Is there any **java Gimp library** to control, resize, or reduce image size (MB to KB) ? I'm looking for something like **JGIMP**.

I tried to work on JGIMP , but it was an older version, and failed to install in fedora 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a working Java Gimp Library but there is a couple of Java interfaces to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) that will let you do everything in your examples.

- [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) provides an object-oriented Java interface to ImageMagick *- unsure of the maintenance state of this the web site is just some downloads*.
- [Im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) is a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick command-line *- since the command line interface is very stable this should work with most versions just new commands will not be supported*.

ImageMagick runs on Linux, Windows, Mac Os X, iOS, Android OS, etc., and by itself provides a command line interface to do just about any image manipulation that you can think of.

You might also like to take a look at [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) which claims: "Pure Java cross-platform image processing framework that provides features for image and video frame processing, multi-threading image processing, GUI integration, extensibility via plug-ins, unit text automation among other things."

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer given by Steve, [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) perfectly suits for your case since it's a framework that you can use to develop your own image processing applications and because it has its own image editor. So you can test the algorithms without developing a software.

**Current Marvin Algorithms:**
http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins.html

**If you want to resize images, take a look at the following question:**
[How do you create a thumbnail image out of a JPEG in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069095/how-do-you-create-a-thumbnail-image-out-of-a-jpeg-in-java/37527828#37527828)

**Marvin Questions on Stack Overflow (Good source of examples):**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marvin-framework

Good luck!